# How to write Farsi in NSIS Custom Page?

Tags: unicode, nsis, custom-pages

I have create a custom page for my installer by NSIS.
I have a label and a textbox in my .INI file. I also use the Unicode version of NSIS.

How can i write a farsi sentence in the text of the label?

It is my .INI file, but it does not show Farsi correctly:

```
 [Settings] 
 NumFields=2
 RTL=1

 [Field 1]
 Type=label
 Text="لطفا آدرس سرور بروز رسانی را وارد نمایید"     
 Left=0     
 Right=-1     
 Top=0     
 Bottom=20

 [Field 2]     
 Type=Text     
 RTL=0     
 Left=0     
 Right=-1     
 Top=30     
 Bottom=45     
 State=""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you use InstallOptions plug-ins.

This plug-in is very old and it is already deprecated.

There may be problem with Unicode in such old plug-in, I found this old topic https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-275900.html where kichik (autor of NSIS) mentioned the Unicode is NOT supported at all! (but the thread is very old and there might be some updates)

Try using nsDialogs plug-in instead which is powerful, stable and much better the IO.

Comment: InstallOptions should support Unicode in NSIS 3 (and probably the Unicode fork)

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing much about NSIS, I'm guessing that it's not reading your .ini file correctly. You should convert the .ini file to UTF-16. You can do it in Notepad - Save As..., encoding: Unicode.